# Connect my pod inside GKE Cluster trough IPSEC VPN to external endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, vpn

I have a K8s cluster deployed in GKE. I have a deployment with a pod deployed in a node with a network in a range 10.4.0.0/14. The cluster is public so it has direct connection to internet.

Now, there is an external service that we have to reach through IPSEC VPN with these specifications (out of GKE)

```
    • IKEv1
    • Mode: Main
    • NAT Traversal enabled, Keep-alive interval: 5 segons
    • IKE Keep-alive, Message interval 30 segons, Max failures: 5
    • Dead peer detection (RFC3706): Traffic based. Traffic iddle timeout: 20. Max retries: 5
    • Authentication: SHA256
    • Encryption: AES (256 bits)
    • SA life: 8 horas
    • Key Group: Diffie-Hellman Group 19
```

How could I config my pod to connect trough VPN using this requirments?

Regards.

Comment: hi @herny, Interested if you managed to solve this issue?